# USB to UART Circuit Issues "Device Not Recognized"

Tags: usb, uart

I recently made a USB to UART circuit using a silicon labs chip [CP2102N-A02-GQFN24](https://componentsearchengine.com/Datasheets/1/CP2102N-A02-GQFN24.pdf) for my homemade espresso machine's motherboard.  I have used a similar silicon labs chip before successfully to upload firmware to MCU but because of this chip shortage I could not get my hands on the one I typically use.  The circuit is meant to upload firmware from my laptop to an MCU (ESP32).  But as soon as I plug in the micro-USB I get the device not recognized error, which I know is bad news.

I have verified the chip is receiving the 3.3V supply voltage, verified component placements, and checked for shorts on the bridge chip.  But I am at a loss of what could be causing the problem, does anyone know what the heck I am doing wrong?

**Edit:**
I rearranged the wires in the USB cable that I connect to this board to match the incorrect usb pin order on the PCB as pointed out by brhans.  Not sure how this error was made!  After doing so the device was recognized.  But just one problem, all firmware uploads fail to connect to the MCU.  I have included 2 additional diagrams from the help text which I thought would aid in locating the problem.  The first one is the diagram I use for the power scheme of this chip and the second is the data connection scheme.  Combining these two diagrams gives the entire circuit, and I think that based on this information my circuit should be working, but clearly this is not the case.

One red flag that I see is that the manual lists 3 power supply options, of which I chose option 3 (device internal regulator not used).  The manual then goes on to list how to connect the data pins which is the other image I shared.  However, they only list two layouts, which are bus powered and self powered.  I don't think this covers my power scenario, but I am not sure what I would do here...

[image: schematic]

[image: layout]

[image: manual excerpt1]

[image: manual excerpt2]

Comment: Are you sure about the pinout on your USB connector? The numbering looks all jumbled up and not having D+ & D- next to each other is really strange ...

Comment: Dang, I don't know how the micro USB layout happened this is totally wrong

Comment: The pinout on the schematic symbol and the pinout on the PCB footprint probably do not match. That is probably the explanation for how they got so messed up. This is a common pain point in PCB design when using a part for the first time.

Comment: @Feynman137 a bit late probably... ^^ But I'm sure the SUSPENDb output doesn't need to be grounded. That's one difference between the A01 and A02. The A02 only has SUSPEND *outputs*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to power VIO, most likely 3V3 on your case.

Page 29 of the datasheet:

5 VIO I/O Supply Power **Input**

Comment: I just edited the question, but I am using figures 2.3 and 2.6 as my reference from the manual, and they don't seem to indicate a need to power VIO.

Comment: @Feynman137, neither 2.3 nor 2.6 seem to indicate anything at all about vio except that RSTb needs to be pulled up to vio with a 1k resistor. You can't conclude from those diagrams that vio does not need to be powered.

Comment: @mkeith you may be right and that would be great but I don’t see where this is supported.  I am looking through the data sheet further…

Comment: @Feynman137 page 29, as Damien says. Also table 3.1, recommended operating conditions. Please note that it is understood by all experienced engineers that "VIO" is intended to be the same voltage rail as the serial port signals. In other words, I am 100 percent sure you need to connect it based on my experience designing circuits professionally for many years. This is not an ego thing. I am just trying to help you.

Comment: Mkeith, not a problem.  I appreciate the help and will give this a go!

Comment: You were correct as was Damien.  I jumpered VIO to 3.3V and was able to connect to the board!

Comment: The datasheet isn't very clear, as mkeith mentioned, VIO is usually the power input of the chip for the digital side so when a pin is called VIO, you can assume it's a voltage input.